# how to call another class which extends View class in fragment and set it as layout

Tags: android-layout

i have made a fragment and also made a class which extends View class in which i have made

a canvas and in that class i set an image in onDraw() method. now i want to set the layout

of my fragment as a canvas mean i want to call and set the canvas with image in my

fragment. because Activity class has a setContentView() Method and Fragment has

onCreateView() method so how i can do this.here is my code:

```
myFragment.java

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflate , ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) { 

View v = inflater.inflate(new myView(this),container,false);

return v;

}

myView.java

onDraw(Canvas c){

c.drawBitmap(bitmap,10,10,mPaint);

}
```